# Alignment over multiple equations

Tags: equations, align, alignment, chemistry

Hi I would like to to align multiple equations. There is always a little bit of text in-between the equations. Basically I would like to have one alignment on the : and one before the arrow over all equations.

Thanks for the help.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}

 \noindent Initiation:
 
 Photochemical: 
 \begin{equation}
    \begin{alignedat}{3}
        K_{UV} &: M[1] \ch{&&-> M^{•}}[1]
    \end{alignedat}
    \label{eq:initPhoto}
 \end{equation} 
 
 Catalyzed:
 \begin{equation}
    \begin{alignedat}{3}
        K_I &: I \ch{&&->} 2R \\
        K_S &: R + M [1] \ch{&&-> RM^{•}}[1]
    \end{alignedat}
    \label{eq:initCat}
 \end{equation} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope it will help you;
**taken from [Beautiful LaTeX open-source eBook (example 1.8).](https://github.com/AnMnv/eBook)**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
\intertext{Photochemical:}
K_{UV} &: M[1]& &\ch{-> M^{•}}[1]
\intertext{Catalyzed:}
K_I &: I& &\ch{->} 2R \\
K_S &: R + M [1]& &\ch{-> RM^{•}}[1]
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Also consider `\shortintertext` with `mathtools`

Comment: Thank You for the tip. The alignment is exactly how I would like it the problem now though is that I am missing the numbering after the equations and I can only label the entire alignat enviorment once which doesn`t allow me to individually refrence each eqaution.

Comment: I figured out I could use alignat with \nonumber, but then the number is always only at the last equation and not centered between two. Is there a way to achieve this?